# About multiple session browsers schema

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

This may sound a dummy question and I acknowledge risking a negative vote, probably a question like this should be better on 'quora' or other forums, but stack, you always so helpfull

A) **how's named the "app" level exactly ?**

I mean, moderns (basically all) browsers have tabs, and each conform a session (with dedicated BOM / JS / sessionStorage / and so on).
But, cookies, localStorage, can be said to be at the **APP** level ??

I find extremely difficult to find literature on APP vs SESSION on this matter

B) **has this schema sense on others than browsers ?**

WEB technology can be easily ported to other platforms (mobile with Cordova/Electron, Desktop with AdobeAir, and others like smartThings...) so we were thinking if the 'sessions schema' has sense in other devices/apps than browsers.

Any example about it ??